# how to add photos while user register?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new developer on iphone. My problem is in iphone I want develop one application in that app I designed one user register form in that I provide some columns (userid, password, dob etc) in that I want to add another column, for example a user can upload photo and save all this information in sqlite database image also (image store in thumb size). Please help to me upload the image (that images are already store in our iphone gallery).

Answer (score 0):

to get images fro camera roll use -

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

and from library use -

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```